# How to make a checkpoint for reverting back in perforce?

Tags: branch, perforce, branching-and-merging, perforce-client-spec, perforce-branch-spec

I am new to perforce.

I have a old copy of code in my local disk and i have made some changes. I have shelved my changes. Other people also have made changes in their code. I want to fetch the new code from the server but also want to make a checkpoint that i can revert to when i need to.

How can i do that ?

In some part of code, i create a sub process whose name is foo.exe. It has been changed to bar.exe by somebody in the new code. When i would fetch the new code, it would spawn the bar.exe. This is an example. Their can be many more changes. i want to put a checkpoint on all the files so that each one of them get reverted to my current version.

Do i need to shelve each file ?

Comment: What I personally do is create a changeset, shelve it, and in the changeset description make a note of what changeset I was synced to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like labels would be useful for you.  labels are generally used to ID release file sets or something similar and allow you to revert the files in your work space to the state held when the files were labelled.

This should cover it.

[P4 Guide: Labels](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.labels.html)

Comment: I found more info on this : http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/Managing_labels.html